# Firefox HTTP auth dialog not modal

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, http, authentication

It is possible to make HTTP authentification dialog in Firefox not modal?

I do NOT want any auto-submit addon (LastPass, AutoAuth), or anything that remebers password and then submits it automatically. I would like to enter credentials "per tab" and any time I want.